# Mudar esquema de cor do Angular 9 material design

Tags: angular, angular-material

Adicionei o pacote do material design, ng add @angular/material, no meu projeto e selecionei o Deep Purple/Amber. Quero mudar a paleta de cores do meu projeto, mas não encontrei como gerar o CSS no site https://material.io/resources/color/

As cores do projeto estão no CSS e não definidos em algum SCSS externo.

Sabem onde consigo gerar um novo CSS? ou Alterar via NPM?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer criar seu proprio tema ou usar um outro dos pré-existentes? Como indigo-pink, pink-bluegrey, purple-green.css.

Comment: Quero usar um tema com cor diferente dos temas pré-definidos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve implementar alterar o style.scss conforme abaixo:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as `color` or `typography`.
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
    warn: $candy-app-warn,  
  )
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

> Fonte: [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Caso você prefira um tema Dark, você deve alterar linha correspondente para o código abaixo:

```
// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as `color` or `typography`.
$candy-app-theme: mat-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
    warn: $candy-app-warn,  
  )
));
```

As cores disponíveis são: `$mat-red, $mat-pink, $mat-purple, $mat-deep-purple, $mat-indigo, $mat-blue, $mat-light-blue, $mat-cyan, $mat-teal, $mat-green, $mat-light-green, $mat-lime, $mat-yellow, $mat-amber, $mat-orange, $mat-deep-orange, $mat-brown, $mat-grey, $mat-blue-grey`.

Mas digamos que você queira uma cor que não está na lista de cores acima, neste caso recorra ao site [Material Design Palette Generator](http://mcg.mbitson.com/), de uma nome a sua palheta, ajuste para a cor desejada, e revise as cores de contraste para ficar de boa, e clique na prancheta para ver o código, escolha `Angular JS 2 (Material 2)` e tá lá, copie e cole no style.scss e use na construção do tema.

Como você criou seu projeto usando um tema padrão, pode ser necessário alterar o `angular.json` para apontar pro `style.scss`, seria no ponto abaixo:

```
projects/[SEU_APP]/architect/build/options/styles
```

> Veja a documentação [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options)

Uma última dica, de uma olhada no projeto de Schematics que estou desenvolvendo:

[angular-mat-baum](https://github.com/baumblatt/angular-mat-baum)

Espero que goste!

Abraços,
Bernardo Baumblatt

Comment: Legal o projeto.. valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo **src/style.css**, adicione:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/NOME_DO_TEMA';
```

Temas disponíveis.

- deeppurple-amber.css
- indigo-pink.css
- pink-bluegrey.css
- purple-green.css

Fonte:
[Usando um tema pré-construído](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme)